# asp.net code first many to many with the same table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, many-to-many

To make the M: M relation work must:
{In Remove Class I should set the IDs(TL_Id, JD_ID, PM_ID) as Users Class ID name (UserId) to work, and so on with object Users names(TL, JD, PM)}.

Is there any way to make this work????

```
public class Users
{
   [Key]
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public String job_description { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Remove> Remove{ get; set; }
}

public class Remove
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int TL_Id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int JD_ID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int PM_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Users TL { get; set; }
    public virtual Users JD { get; set; }
    public virtual Users PM { get; set; }

    public string remove_request { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need exactly this. You need to add additional property to Remove class:

```
public class Remove
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int TL_Id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int JD_ID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int PM_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Users RemoveListed{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Create a FK by Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Remove>()  
    .HasRequired(c => c.RemoveListed)  
    .WithMany(d => d.Remove)
    .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.TL_Id , d.JD_ID, d.PM_ID });
```

Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships

> Important! Users.Remove will iterate over Remove.RemoveListed.

I think this is not what you want. In this case, I believe that the data structure should be revised.

> This is one-to-many relationship. Many-to-many required List for each other in both entities.